# Universal Links on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, ios-universal-links

Can I test the implementation of universal links for my ios-application, on the simulator, without uploading Association File? I'm using 'xcrun simctl openurl' to open link.

Answer (score 0):

you can check using URL Schemes like add your prefix in URL schemes. 
Open safari add your prefix + add "://" at last and then check
like "prefix://"
you can check also below link

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but I am trying to use Universal Links.